# Where does $rows come from in views?

Tags: views

Let's say I have a simplest "unformated list" view.

I see that "views-view-unformatted.tpl.php" is outputting $rows in a loop.

When I open my view page on a browser, I see that the following codes are generated by $row.

```
<span class="field-content"><a href="/node/264">test1</a></span>
```

What template can I edit to remove anchor part?

Answer (score 0):

Non need to edit template in this case.
Just edit title field and uncheck "Link this field to the original piece of content" option.